# How to write this line in a for loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, random-forest

[I am confused about how to write a for loop in R for lines 1 and 2, especially line 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI2Vy.jpg)

my code for the random forest is

```
set.seed(415)
fit1 <- randomForest(as.factor(Survived) ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare +
                     Embarked + Title + FamilySize + FamilyID,
                     data = train, 
                     importance = TRUE, 
                     ntree = 1000)
```

And I also have a random forest with 999 trees -- not exactly sure if its necessary or not, and I have fixed prediction accuracy of 83.16% for 1000 trees and 83.05% for 999 trees. I'm not sure if that's the way to do it.

Comment: What precisely is your question? Would you like to build 1000 trees using the [randomForest CRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html)?

Comment: I already have a random forest but I need to build a for loop in order to calculate which one of the trees does not or barely affects the overall prediction accuracy of the forest and remove that one.

Comment: So you want to iterate through the 1000 trees within the `fit1` object?